# I want a particular format array from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to modify the existing array to a particular format please see the below array what i have and what i want

I have array as :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [block_id] => 1
            [title] => Test1
            [identifier] => test1
            [content] => some test data
            [creation_time] => 2019-09-03 09:47:35
            [update_time] => 2019-09-03 09:47:35
            [is_active] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [block_id] => 2
            [title] => test2
            [identifier] => twst2
            [content] => dfdsffsdfsdfsfsdf
            [creation_time] => 2019-09-03 09:48:03
            [update_time] => 2019-09-03 09:48:03
            [is_active] => 1
        )

)
```

And I want this array as :

```
$options = [
        ['value' => 'test1', 'label' => __('Test1')],
        ['value' => 'test2', 'label' => __('Test2')],
        ['value' => 'test3', 'label' => __('Test3')],
        ['value' => 'test4', 'label' => __('Test4')],
        ['value' => 'test5', 'label' => __('Test5')],
        ['value' => 'test6', 'label' => __('Test6')]
        ];
```

Comment: You missed out the bit which shows what you have tried so far to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution.

```
$data = Array ( Array
            (
                'block_id' => 1,
                'title' => 'Test1'
            ), Array
            (
                'block_id' => 2,
                'title' => 'test2'
            )

            );

    foreach($data as $k => $val){

        $options[$k]['value'] = $val['title'];
        $options[$k]['label'] = '__("'.ucfirst($val['title']).'")';

    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $options);
```

Expected Result is

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => Test1
            [label] => __("Test1")
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => test2
            [label] => __("Test2")
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If $array is your array, then

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
    $options[] = [ 'value' => $v['identifier'], 'label' => "__('" . $v['title'] . "')"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying *"to modify the existing array to a particular format"* , next approach may help. When you precede `$value` with `&`, the `$value` will be assigned by reference and you can directly modify it.

```
<?php
foreach($array as &$value) {
    $value = array(
        'value' => $value["identifier"],
        'label' => "__('".$value["title"]."')"
    );
};
unset($value);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution.

foreach ($array as $k => $val)
{
    $options[] = [ 'val' => $val['identifier'], 'label' => "__('" . $val['title'] . "')"];
}